# WildFly can't find beans.xml in the Arquillian Assembly

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, junit, wildfly, jboss-arquillian

Hi I'm studying Arquillian there is one pom.xml:

```
<packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>

        <!-- Jakarta EE API -->
        <jakartaee-api.version>9.0.0-RC1</jakartaee-api.version>
        <!-- Arquillian BOM -->
        <arquillian-bom.version>1.6.0.Final</arquillian-bom.version>
        <!-- JUnit4 -->
        <junit.version>4.13</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
                <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
                <version>${jakartaee-api.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${arquillian-bom.version}</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>${junit.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>arq-wildfly-remote</id>
            <properties>
                <skipTests>false</skipTests>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.wildfly.arquillian</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-remote</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.1.Final</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <systemPropertyVariables>
                                <arquillian.launch>wildfly-remote</arquillian.launch>
                                <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                            </systemPropertyVariables>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipITs>${skipTests}</skipITs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <id>integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/it/**</include>
                            </includes>
                            <reportsDirectory>
                                ${project.build.directory}/test-reports/it
                            </reportsDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

File arquillian.xml:

```
<arquillian
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian
    http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">
    <defaultProtocol type="Servlet 3.0" />

    <engine>
        <property name="deploymentExportPath">target/</property>
    </engine>

    <container qualifier="wildfly-remote" default="true">
        <configuration>
            <property name="managementAddress">127.0.0.1</property>
            <property name="managementPort">9990</property>
            <property name="protocol">http</property>
            <property name="username">admin</property>
            <property name="password">admin</property>
        </configuration>
    </container>

</arquillian>
```

File beans.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_2_0.xsd"
       bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

I made a simple class to test how @Inject works

```
public class TestCDI {
    public TestCDI() {
        System.out.println("Hello TestCDI");
    }
}
```

The actual class (@Inject from jakarta. inject.Inject):

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class TestCDITest {

    @Deployment
    public static Archive<?> createDeployment() {
        return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class)
                .addPackages(true, TestCDI.class.getPackage())
                .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
    }

    @Inject
    TestCDI testCDI;

    @Test
    public void isNull() {
        Assert.assertNotNull(testCDI);
    }

}
```

On startup: `mvn clean verify -Parq-wildfly-remote`

I see a connection to the server, and a warning in the log:

```
21:33:45,513 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYWELD0013: Deployment 9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war contains CDI annotations but no bean archive was found (no beans.xml or class with bean defining annotations was present).
21:33:45,532 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 140) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335' for server 'default-server'
21:33:45,544 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 7) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war" (runtime-name : "9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war")
21:33:45,948 INFO  [org.jboss.arquillian.testenricher.cdi.container.BeanManagerProducer] (default task-1) BeanManager not found.
21:33:46,013 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 140) WFLYUT0022: Unregistered web context: '/9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335' from server 'default-server'
21:33:46,029 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment 9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war (runtime-name: 9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war) in 17ms
21:33:46,045 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (management-handler-thread - 8) WFLYDR0002: Content removed from location /home/sergey/Загрузки/wildfly-21.0.0.Final/standalone/data/content/b5/8c1bf6477e7ecb6f6c98e4339911f76bc00f22/content
21:33:46,045 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 8) WFLYSRV0009: Undeployed "9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war" (runtime-name: "9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war")
```

Test to fall with such errors:

```
java.lang.AssertionError
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:87)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:42)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull(Assert.java:713)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull(Assert.java:723)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//ru.sfedu.repositories.model.TestCDITest.isNull(TestCDITest.java:31)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$8$1.invokeMethod(Arquillian.java:325)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.jboss.arquillian.junit.MethodInvoker$1.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:18)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.LocalTestExecuter.execute(LocalTestExecuter.java:57)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:133)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:105)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:62)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.ContainerTestExecuter.execute(ContainerTestExecuter.java:36)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:103)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:90)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createTestContext(TestContextHandler.java:116)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:69)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:133)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.test(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:139)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$200(Arquillian.java:54)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$5.evaluate(Arquillian.java:215)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$7$1.invoke(Arquillian.java:279)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.BeforeLifecycleEventExecuter.on(BeforeLifecycleEventExecuter.java:34)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:103)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:90)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createTestContext(TestContextHandler.java:116)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:69)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:133)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:105)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.fireCustomLifecycle(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:159)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$7.evaluate(Arquillian.java:273)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$2.evaluate(Arquillian.java:166)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:350)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$200(Arquillian.java:54)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:177)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:115)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.jboss.arquillian.junit.container.JUnitTestRunner.execute(JUnitTestRunner.java:61)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.runner.ServletTestRunner.executeTest(ServletTestRunner.java:139)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.runner.ServletTestRunner.execute(ServletTestRunner.java:117)
        at deployment.9236468a-1bfb-4b55-941f-325f506a9335.war//org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.runner.ServletTestRunner.doGet(ServletTestRunner.java:86)
        at javax.servlet.api@2.0.0.Final//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:503)
        at javax.servlet.api@2.0.0.Final//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at org.jboss.xnio@3.8.2.Final//org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1280)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I've already tried dragging beans.xml in:

- resource/META-INF/
- webapp/WEB-INF/
- test/resource/

And also in the createDeployment method changed the paths to beans.xml

Tell me what the problem is, why the application server does not see beans.xml in the archive.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an empty file called beans.xml with this code:

> .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");

This is wrong, pass the content of your file as a String or just add it.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`.addAsWebInfResource(new File("your/path/to/beans.xml"))`

For WAR packaging, the `beans.xml` file should end up in the `WEB-INF` directory so you should add it to your deployment using the `addAsWebInfResource` method instead of `addAsManifestResource`. The remark by Ehsavoie is also valid, you're adding an empty `beans.xml` file (which is not technically wrong if you deploy to a JavaEE7 or JavaEE8 container, which I assume is the case), but obviously it will not have the contents you planned.